# "Current position is after the last row" when ResultSet#getRow() returns 1

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

In MySQL `ResultSet#getRow()` returns < 1 when cursor position is after the last row. I just switched to MariaDB. I'm calling `ResultSet#next()` and after that `ResultSet#getRow()`. When the result set is empty `ResultSet#getRow()` returns 1 for MariaDB.

There is a lot of code to change if this really is how MariaDB works. Or am I doing something wrong and the problem exists only for me?

`ResultSet` is `java.sql.ResultSet`. MariaDB version is 10.0.14 on RHEL 7.0. I'm using *mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar* with Tomcat 8.0.15 and Java 8.

Comment: This seems like a bug to me; according to the specs, `ResultSet#getRow()` should return 0 if there is no current row. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getRow()

Comment: So it looks like a bug in MariaDB JDBC driver. Has anyone else faced the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a bug in MariaDB. I'm pretty sure, by looking at their source, that if you called another `next()`, you'll get `2` and so on. This is how they implement `next()` in their `CachedResultSet`.

```
public boolean next() throws IOException, QueryException{
    rowPointer++;
    return rowPointer < resultSet.size();
}
```

And from looking at their `StreamingResultSet` code, you're not going to be any happier if you switch to streaming result sets, as those will throw an exception if you call `getRow()`.

I would advise you to change your code so that it checks the result of `next()` rather than relying on `getRow()` which, according to the JDBC documentation, is an optional method. Even if you report this bug to the developers of MariaDB and they fix it, you'll run into trouble as soon as your result sets are big enough for you to switch to their streaming mode (by changing the statement's fetch size). And if you switch to any other database that does not implement `getRow()` you'll run into similar trouble.

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I should avoid `getRow()` in the future. Now I'm using it for other things also than just checking if I'm past the last row. Need to go thru my code and see how easy it is to fix. I may need to go back to MySQL for now.

Comment: cc: @PanuHaaramo - Yes, another `next()` followed by another `getRow()` does return 2. I can also confirm that in both cases the `next()` correctly returned `false`. (mariadb-java-client-1.1.7.jar, Java 7, Windows 8.1)